# What is angular $templatecache? How can i use in an application to prevent hard refresh every time if i modify any template in an application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is angular `$template-cache`? How can I use it in an application to prevent hard refresh every time if I modify any template in an application.
Please explain to me with an example.

Comment: _prevent hard refresh every time if i modify any template in an application_ - what is hard refresh? where do you modify a template?

Comment: template is an html file and hard refresh means reloading the page disabling the browser cache

Comment: ok atleast please explain me how we can use $templatecache in an angular application

Comment: please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$templateCache` service is used to store templates (html strings). If you write a directive with `templateUrl` or use `ngInclude` directive, angular resolves the path to template and sends network request in runtime to retrieve it. When template arrives, it's put into `$templateCache` using `path` as a key. Whenever this same template is requested by a directive next time, the network request is not made and instead the template string is retrieved from the `$templateCache`.

You can use this `$templateCache` to put templates there when you angular app starts and in this way you'll save network requests and decrease loading time. For example, like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the template');
});
```

There are tasks that can help you do it automatically. For example, `grunt-angular-templates` for grunt.